# Filter by Array Length in OData

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

I want to filter based on the length of data. For example, I want to retrieve only the images array that contains more than 1 element. Something like that images.length > 6.

Is this possible using OData. Your help is much appreciated

```html
{
      "@search.score": 1,
      "site": "core",
      "images": [
        {
          "alt": "Quad"
        }
      ]
    },    ,{
      "@search.score": 1,
      "site": "ccc",
      "images": [
        {
          "alt": "some"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 1,
      "site": "ccc",
      "images": [
        {
          "alt": "DePaul's Student Center"
        },
        {
          "alt": "O'Malley"
        },
        {
          "alt": "Campus"
        },
        {
          "alt": " Campus"
        },
        {
          "alt": "ith students"
        },
        {
          "alt": "er"
        },
        {
          "alt": "df"
        },
        {
          "alt": "sdf"
        },
        {
          "alt": "df"
        },

      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and better solution is to populate your data with an additional property called ImageCount. If you submit your items via the Azure Search SDK, you can process them before submitting them to search. Add the image count to each item and then filter like normal.

$filter=ImageCount gt 6